Varying asm x64 Linux chars array
I'm learning asm for feew days and I face some problems. I need to print some text (exemple int to string, or variable string) in asm and I use buffer for now. I have asm function that could write any string whatever the size :
.print:
    push rcx                    ; save increment if used in another function
    xor rcx, rcx                ; reset increment to 0

.print_loop:
    cmp byte [rsi + rcx], 0     ; check if null
    je .print_done              ; if yes print the value beacause end of string
    inc rcx                     ; else increment 
    jmp .print_loop             ; and restart the operation

.print_done:
    mov rdx, rcx                ; pass the string size as parameter syscall sys_write
    mov rax, 1                  ; prepare syscall sys_write function
    mov rdi, 1                  ; prepare syscall stdout output
    syscall                     ; print the string
    pop rcx                     ; get the old increment value to handle return
    ret

But buffer are very annoying if my string is bigger because I'm forced to initialize a new buffer every time I need to display a string, and cannot handle the string concatenation if my new string is bigger than my allowed space.
section .bss
    buffer resb 20                  ; Buffer for int to string
    buffer resb 100                 ; buffer for message and other text
    ; ... other buffer if needed

I have some idea to implement variable string but they look bad... I think i can use brk but I prefer to not use bss section and idem for mmap. I sense I can use the stack to create local variable and move the base pointer to handle my new stack substack, but I don't think this is a good solution, especially when I have to concatenate my new string.
If anybody know how to create chars array, I'll take any advice and information
I already tried to create space in my stack and free it later if I need to concat my string but it create big empty space in my memory. And it's not simple to use subq    ${size_needed}, %rsp dynamically to create local variables in the next function call. I'm not sure it's a good practice.
I also already tried .bss declaration, but I need one declaration by string and this is very bad I think.

You can make separate write system calls for the parts of a string if the total length is too large for a static buffer you were going to use.  For example the C stdio library would make a write system call to empty its fixed-size buffer part-way through a big printf("%s %s %s", ...).  Or use writev to pass the kernel multiple pointers+lengths and let it gather them. (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/readv.2.html).  If you don't need to concat multiple strings, you can just pass the pointer+length to write directly without copying it anywhere first.

Of course you could just call C stdio functions like fputs to get write buffering done for you.

The solution of calling write multiple times appeals to me; I don't have any particular limits on memory or speed. So I'm not going to focus on optimization.
However, I do have a double problem: I need to concatenate several strings of unknown length (for example, I have an int that is converted to a string and can be 3 characters long if I pass 200, but 6 if I pass 600000). Do you have any ideas on how I could create dynamic character strings, similar to std::string, but much simpler?

For int-to-string, the upper limit on buffer size is tiny, only 9 or 19 bytes (32 or 64-bit integers), so just allocate 32 or 24 bytes on the stack and write from there, as shown in How do I print an integer in Assembly Level Programming without printf from the c library? (itoa, integer to decimal ASCII string).  That's written as a callable function so it effectively deallocs the buffer after one use, but if you have multiple separate uses for a buffer whose lifetimes don't overlap, you can reuse the same stack space.
